# Browsing svn with trac browser

Tags: svn, trac

I had a repository and today I installed the Trac, I want to browse my repository through Trac, repository_dir is pointing to my repository folder, but I'm still getting the following error:

```
Error: No such changeset

No changeset 313 in the repository
```

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is your repository on the same server where you installed Trac?  If so, you can access the repository directly instead of going through http.  For example, if your repository was created in `/var/repos/trac`, adding the following into your trac.ini should work:

```
[trac]
repository_dir = /var/repos/trac
```

If your repository is on a different server, I highly recommend either installing Trac on the repository's server or [creating a mirror repository](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.replication) on the Trac server.  Besides making the Trac configuration easier, it results in a much faster Trac server by avoiding the need to fetch repository information over the network.  Create the mirror repository but don't start any kind of Subversion server; Trac can still access it directly via the filesystem, and you don't have to worry about anyone but Trac accessing it.  You can set up a simple script that runs `svnsync synchronize` at regular intervals (mine is set to 5 minutes) to keep your mirror up to date.

---

On another note, using `repository_dir` in trac.ini is no longer the preferred way to set up a repository.  It's usually easier to use the "Repositories" panel of Trac's admin panel (see [the official documentation](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracRepositoryAdmin) for more details).  If you go that route, make sure to delete the existing `repository_dir` entry from your trac.ini first.

Comment: afaik after setting/changing the repository dir a `trac-admin resync` is required.

Comment: I didn't synchronized, and that was the problem. Thanks.

Comment: One more question, how can I control the access to the repository?

Comment: @iUngi- Through Trac, you can use the Admin panel to give accounts the "BROWSER_VIEW" permission.  Users who do not have this permission will not be able to access the repository viewer component of Trac.

Answer (score 0):

It's an URL problem. By the look of error I guess that you are trying to view commit #313 which doesn't exist in the repository.

Comment: What is the solution in this case?

Comment: I always using http or https, but if I past repository_dir = http://myip/svn/ I will get the following error: Trac Error

/var/www/trac/repos/http:/localhost/svn does not appear to be a Subversion repository.

Comment: Please grep for 313 in your configs, this shouldn't happen